# Travis AWS S3 SDK set cache header for particular file

Tags: amazon-s3, travis-ci

In my Travis script is there a way when uploading contents to S3 Bucket as follows :

```
# deploy:
#   provider: script
#   skip_cleanup: true
#   script: "~/.local/bin/aws s3 sync dist s3://mybucket --region=eu-west-1
#     --delete"
# before_deploy:
# - npm run build
# - pip install --user awscli
```

I also want to set a no cache header on a particular file in that bucket (i.e. sw.js). Is that currently possible in the SDK ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid that this is not possible using a single `s3 sync` command. But you may try to execute two commands using **exclude** and **include** options. One to sync all except the *sw.js* and the other one just for *sw.js*.

`script: ~/.local/bin/aws s3 sync dist s3://mybucket --include "*" --exclude "sw.js" --region eu-west-1 --delete ; ~/.local/bin/aws s3 sync dist s3://mybucket --exclude "*" --include "sw.js" --region eu-west-1 --delete --cache-control "no-cache" --metadata-directive REPLACE`

Note: `--metadata-directive REPLACE` option is necessary for non-multipart copies.